# bool multiplication with exclusive-or, not or (with Eigen Matrix Library)

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, hamming-code, eigen3

I'm trying to implement hamming error correcting codes, and to do this I need to take a bool Vector (the data) and multiply it with a bool Matrix(hamming generator matrix), performing XOR operations (instead of what looks like OR as Eigen's default bool behavior). An example of what I am doing is found in this simple tutorial: http://michael.dipperstein.com/hamming/

I don't necessarily have to use Eigen, so please feel free to suggest something other than Eigen if you have the solution.

So for example a bit of C++ code that compiles, but does not quite work the right way:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

typedef Eigen::Matrix<bool, 4, 7> Matrix4by7Bool;
typedef Eigen::Matrix<bool, 1, 4> Vector4Bool;
int main()
{
Matrix4by7Bool gm;
gm << 0,1,1,1,0,0,0,
      1,0,1,0,1,0,0,
      1,1,0,0,0,1,0,
      1,1,1,0,0,0,1;

Vector4Bool dm;
dm << 1,0,1,0;

cout << dm * gm;
}
```

currently results in: 1 1 1 1 0 1 0
but I need: 1 0 1 1 0 1 0

The difference is that the default behavior is to multiply and then OR each multiplication. Since I need XOR instead of OR, wondering what the best way to do this with Eigen is?

Happy to try and elaborate if this does not make sense.

BTW, not sure if it matters but I'm working on a MacBook Air, using G++. Just downloaded Eigen today so its prob the newest available (eigen3)

Thank you,
Keith

**UPDATE: Given the accepted solution below, I wanted to repost the correct code as reference for people:**

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

typedef Eigen::Array<bool, 4, 7> Array4by7Bool;
typedef Eigen::Array<bool, 4, 1> Array1by4Bool;

struct logical_xor {
  bool operator() (bool a, bool b) const
  {
    return a != b;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Array4by7Bool gm;
  gm << 0,1,1,1,0,0,0,
        1,0,1,0,1,0,0,
        1,1,0,0,0,1,0,
        1,1,1,0,0,0,1;

  Array1by4Bool dm;
  dm << 1,0,1,0;

  cout << "result: "  <<  (gm.colwise() * dm).colwise().redux(logical_xor()) << endl;
}
```

Comment: You might be able to write your own function using a `for` loop and the XOR operator^().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can mimic a matrix_vector product using broadcasting and a partial reduction:

```
struct logical_xor { bool operator(bool a, bool b) { return a != b; }
result = (gm.array().colwise() * dm.transpose().array()).colwise().redux(logical_xor());
```

If you declare your variables as Array and dm is already a column array, then this simplifies to:

```
result = (gm.colwise() * dm).colwise().redux(logical_xor());
```

Comment: This is concise.  Wondering though if there is a performance hit because the multiplication operation happens, followed by the broadcast operation.  Whereas in us202's answer it seems like its just a redefinition of the operation?  Not clear enough on Eigen internals to know if this is true or how much this performance hit is happening...

Comment: +1 from me for this solution because unlike my answer, this approach makes it clear that XOR is not actually (mathematically) a type of addition. I don't think you'll face a massive performance hit - my solution may have problems too if the compiler doesn't inline the operators or stuff like that. If this is massively performance-critical, benchmark both solutions and compare with a different approach that doesn't use Eigen.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* do that. The below is a proof of concept. It contains the minimum you need to make your example compile and give your desired result.

It is probably rather fragile, and it's c&p'ed from other code I had lying around, so it won't earn any points for being pretty or idiomatic.

The basic idea is that you create your own `bool` type where addition is XOR, and the give the relevant operators and `NumTraits` you need.

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

class mybool {
public:
  bool b;
  mybool() { b = false; }
  mybool(bool b) : b(b) {}
  mybool(int a) : b(a!=0) {}
  mybool operator* (const mybool m) const {return m.b & b;} 
  mybool operator+ (const mybool m) const {return m.b ^ b;} 
  mybool operator+= (const mybool m) {b ^= m.b; return b;}
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const mybool& m);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const mybool& m) { os << m.b; return os; }

namespace Eigen {
template<> struct NumTraits<mybool>
{
  typedef int Real;
  typedef mybool Nested;
  enum {
    IsComplex = 0,
    IsInteger = 1,
    IsSigned = 0,
    RequireInitialization = 0,
    ReadCost = 1,
    AddCost = 2,
    MulCost = 2
  };
  static Real epsilon() { return 1; }
};
}


typedef Matrix<mybool, 4, 7> Matrix4by7Bool;
typedef Matrix<mybool, 1, 4> Vector4Bool;
int main()
{
  Matrix4by7Bool gm;
  gm << 0,1,1,1,0,0,0,
        1,0,1,0,1,0,0,
        1,1,0,0,0,1,0,
       1,1,1,0,0,0,1;

  Vector4Bool dm;
  dm << 1,0,1,0;

  cout << dm * gm;
}
```