# Hamming distance through Eigen and std::bitset

Tags: c++, matlab, c++11, matrix, eigen

I have an `Eigen::Matrix<bool,Dynamic,Dynamic> H (p,b)` as result of the equivalent matlab operation `H = (K*W)>0;` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38367672/eigen-how-can-i-substitute-matrix-positive-values-with-1-and-0-otherwise) question for more details).

However, I have to compute the hamming distance between each row of `H` and a vector `v`. Since it's easy and fast to compute it between two `std::bitset` `a` and `b`  through `(a^b).count()` I was wondering if it's possible to implement `H = (K*W)>0;` where `H` is `Eigen::Array<std::bitset,Dynamic,1>`.

As alternative, [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838959/bool-multiplication-with-exclusive-or-not-or-with-eigen-matrix-library) this question I have the feeling that I can use `redux()` for `Eigen::Matrix<bool,Dynamic,Dynamic> H (p,b)` but I cannot figure out how to define the reduction function

Answer (score 0):

Using `std::bitset` could be difficult as you need to treat `std::bitset` as a customized scalar type and define scalar operations on it.

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizingEigen.html#CustomScalarType

Hamming distance on the other hand is easy, although `.count()` here may be slower than `std::bitset::count()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
using namespace Eigen;

int main() {
  const int p = 5;
  const int b = 10;
  Eigen::Matrix<bool, Dynamic, Dynamic> H(p, b);
  Eigen::Matrix<bool, 1, Dynamic> V(b);
  H.setRandom();
  V.setRandom();

  std::cout << "H:\n" << H << std::endl;
  std::cout << "V:\n" << V << std::endl;
  std::cout << "distance(H, V):\n"
      << (H.array() != V.replicate(p, 1).array()).rowwise().count()
      << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```